# how can I use button images to get the button image source when they are clicked using html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a gallery with buttons using html and css. Currently started learning javascript, so hoping this can be done without it. I'm trying to open a full screen image in a new window once the button is clicked. I'm trying to make the source of each button appear on the new window once the button is clicked. I have over 50 button images, so I was wondering if there's a way to get the source of each image that is clicked and opened full screen on the new window.

This is my gallery of image buttons

[image]

This is the html code for the gallery

[image]

Comment: Put your code here...........

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is there a reason why all of your images are buttons? Your screenshot just looks like a regular gallery page.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't have to use buttons to put a click event on a image. I created an example where you click on a image and transfer its URL to another place. It's the same principle you need. It's a jQuery solution.

Next time, post your code here instead a image.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6tf9uk6x/

```js
$("img.btnImage").on("click", function() {
    $("#selectedImage").html("<img src='"+$(this).attr("src")+"'/>");
});
```

```css
#selectedImage, #selectedImage img {
    width: 100%;
    clear:both;
}

.btnImage {
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" width="100" class="btnImage" />
    <img src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/cat/cat-6.jpg" width="100" class="btnImage" />
</div>

<div id="selectedImage">
    <h1>No image selected</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the buttons links instead.

```
<a target="_blank" href="/assets/RaveCandy/picName.gif">
  <!-- image tag as usual -->
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said  *"I'm trying to open a full screen image in a new window once the button is clicked."*, so you do not need to use button here.

Just make use of anchor tag in a more broad way. Use `target="_blank"` to open `src` of the link in the new window.

Instead of text link inside anchor tag use `img` tag.

```
<a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm"><img src="klematis_small.jpg" alt="Klematis"></a>
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_gallery) is the working example, you may like it.